# how to implement PayPal Adaptive Payment in Omnipay PHP payment processing library

Tags: php, paypal, cakephp-2.3, paypal-adaptive-payments, omnipay

Am using cakephp 2.3 version and implemented PayPal Omnipay PHP payment processing library with PayPal Express Checkout which is working fine. But now i wanted change this to PayPal Adaptive Payments using Omnipay.

If any one already used this please give me suggestion how to implement this. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Omnipay supports PayPal Adaptive Payments.

Is there a specific reason that you want to use PayPal Adaptive Payments? Can I recommend that, since you're already using Omnipay, that you switch to using the PayPal REST gateway? It has better documentation and support these days, and appears to be the way that PayPal is moving for all future payment APIs.